# Python recognizing prefixes

Tags: python-3.x

I am a noob at Python and don't really know much but this is by best guess, I'm suppose to have the user input a year and the input file is suppose to output all the years containing the year or atleast its prefix, so I could enter "1" and all the years starting with "1" will show up...if you could point me in the right direction that would be cool! Thanks in advance

```
year_input = input("Input a year:")

for line in input_file:

    line = line.strip()

    year = line[-4:]


if len(year_input) == year or line[-3:] or line[-2:] or line[-1:]:
    prefix = year == line[-3:] == line[-2:] == line[-1:]
    print(prefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startswith` function, i.e.

```
for line in input_file:

    line = line.strip()

    year = line[-4:]


    if year.startswith(year_input):
        print(year)
```

Comment: But doesnt startswith return a True or False?

Comment: And an if statement requires exactly that.